# Visual Studio 2012 video problems

Tags: visual-studio, video

[image]

Has anyone else encountered a problem such as the one shown in the attached screen shot? When I run VS 2012, if I mouse-over text, I get these chromatic boxes, and if I mouse-over the menus, the words underneath disappear. Similar problems occurred in the installer as well, and if you tab in and out of the source code editor, some times you get gigantic text that fills the whole screen.

Screenshot taken from VS 2012 Web express, but it happens on C# express as well. 2008 and 2010 are installed on the same machine with no problem.

This is a Razer Blade laptop (660M graphics), with the latest nVidia drivers installed and Win 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I solved the visual glitches by turning off hardware acceleration in the VS options menu. Hopefully a fix to either VS or a driver update will allow acceleration to be turned back on without weird side effects.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question just searching for VS2012 display glitches and had the inverse, I was seeing issues where selecting text was sporadic (e.g. it would visually select line 1 and 4 when I'd dragged from line 1 to 4, leaving 2 and 3 unmarked.)

The cursor was also slow to respond when typing fast and in general, any text editor performance was shabby.

I had put this down to running a win8 VM and some other issues I'd had, but on reading your answer I checked the performance setting and found out that hardware acceleration was turned off as it had the 'automatically adjust settings based on performance' option selected.

Turning hardware acceleration back on resolved my issue! Kind of the inverse of your problem but thought it worth adding.